# Img load and nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, append

I'm trying to implement a newsfeed. When the page first loads 20 news items with friend pic data etc. load and all is well.

Then when the user updates their status, I want to show this and any new friend status in the newsfeed. This is the structure I want to create dynamically

```
...
<div id="doNews" class="colwrap st-leftmenu">
  <ul id="theNews" class="newsList">
      <li class="newsItem">
          <div class="st-col2">
            <img class="newsImage" src="profile/16/images/thumb/cloth.gif">
            </img>
          </div>   
          <div class="st-col1">
            <div class="st-name">John Smith</div>
            <!-- other user status divs -->
          </div>
      </li>
      <!-- other lis -->
  </ul>
```

And I've been able to create the `img` part with this jQuery:

```
function showStatus(data){
    var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#doNews').empty();
    $('#doNews').append($('<ul/>', {"class": "newsList", id: "theNews"}));
    $.each(jsondata, function(i, item){
        $('<img src="' + showpic(item[3]) + '" class="newsImage">')
            .load(function(){
        $(this)
            .appendTo($('#theNews'))
            .wrap($('<li>', {"class": "newsItem"}))
            .wrap('<div class="st-col2">');
      });
});
//  $('#theNews li').each(function(){
//      $(this).append($('<div>', {"class": "st-col1"}));
//  });

$("#statustext").val('');
}
```

However, the commented out part doesn't seem to work (b/C the page has already loaded?) And if I put it in the load function, the `<div class="st-col1">` gets attached to the img which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the `li`s in the image load callback so then add the `div` to the `li` there.

```
$('<img src="' + showpic(item[3]) + '" class="newsImage">')
    .load(function(){
        $(this)
            .appendTo($('#theNews'))
            .wrap($('<li>', {"class": "newsItem"}))
            .wrap('<div class="st-col2">')
            .closest('li')
            .append($('<div>', {"class": "st-col1"}));
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function showStatus(data){
    var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#doNews').empty();
    $('#doNews').append($('<ul/>', {"class": "newsList", id: "theNews"}));
    $.each(jsondata, function(i, item){
        $('<img src="' + showpic(item[3]) + '" class="newsImage">')
        .load(function(){
            $('<li>', {"class": "newsItem"})
            .append($('<div />', {"class": "st-col2"}).append(this))
            .append($('<div>', {"class": "st-col1"}))
            .appendTo('#theNews');
        });
    });
    //  $('#theNews li').each(function(){
    //      $(this).append($('<div>', {"class": "st-col1"}));
    //  });

    $("#statustext").val('');
}
```